# How to get property afterwards on a mongoose document?

Tags: mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I try to retrieve/populate the property of an already existing mongoose document ?

I do not want to project the key in my initial find query because i use that property in only 1% percent of my calls...

Any idea ? It seems that populate only works on cross collections refs.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to retrieve document in your MongoDB (i suppose?) database with the mongoose ORM ?

Some functions :

```js
your_mongoose_schema.findOne({your_column: "column1"},function(err, doc) {
  //return the first document that have column1 for your_column attributes
 // doc.your_column = "column1"
})
```

```js
your_mongoose_schema.find({your_column: "column1"},function(err, docs) {
  //docs = array with all the docs that have "column1" for your_column attributes 
})
```

If you want to retrive a document without the _id property :

```js
your_mongoose_schema.find({your_column: "column1"}, { '_id': 0, 'column1' :1}, function(err, doc){

});
```